# System.Web.WebSocket vs SignalR

Tags: asp.net, node.js, websocket, signalr

It's seems to me that SignalR is only temporary step towards global domination of System.Web.WebSocket, and it's lower level System.Net.WebSocket.

If I have IIS8, and my clients have IE10, do I have any reason to use signalR?
Does it have a future?

(Of course, the same goes for Socket.IO + Node.js)

Thanks

ref:
http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/websockets-vs-signalr-or-why-you-should-not-have-to-care/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of advantages:

1. SignalR abstracts the actual connection type away so that you only deal with a logical connection. The advantage is that you can switch to other connection types if you want to without having to change your code (SSE might actually provide better performance than WebSockets in some cases).
2. You get the fallback options (long-polling etc.) for free in case you need to connect from a client that doesn't support WebSockets.
3. Hubs provide a level of organization (you can do that yourself, of course, but it's a good starting point, and it's convenient)
4. SignalR provides a rich API for calling a specific client, a group of clients, all clients (including the ability to exclude certain clients). Again, you can implement it yourself, so this is mostly about convenience.
5. You can pass strongly typed parameters between client and server (both ways).
6. You'll (probably) have to deal with less boilerplate code with SignalR.
7. [Scale-out](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr) support

Comment: Thanks. I missed out the scale thingi.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the [group membership/broadcast](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/working-with-groups) and the ability to [scale out](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr) on a webfarm are features that you don't get built into the `WebSockets` classes - so if you're using those features, you'll probably continue to use SignalR for the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Damien's points:

- SignalR also supports long polling and some other techniques if the user has no browser with web socket support
- It's very easy to call methods on the client from the server

Answer (score 0):

Also, when WebSockets is updated, SignalR will also be updated, so you won't need to worry about coding for the new version of WebSockets.